# What is the limit of the given inequality

Tags: limits

Suppose the inequality $\frac {1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{24}<\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}<\frac {1}{2}$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}$ is?   I already solved this question by taking limit on the inequalities the answer is $\frac{1}{2}<\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}<\frac{1}{2}$ but I have a small doubt, as we know  if $a<f(x)<a \implies f(x)=\phi$ so the solution is $1/2$ or doesn't exist?

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: For open interval $f(x)\in to (a, a ) f(x)=$\phi$ now my question is the limit of the question is 1/2 or doesn't exist

Comment: @mSourav refer to squeeze theorem and to the proof here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Proof_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x\ne 0$,

$$\left(\frac12-\frac{x^2}{24},\frac12\right)\ne \emptyset$$ and $\dfrac12$ is an accumulation point.

Limits are always computed in neighborhoods, not on the point itself.

---

You may reassure yourself by writing

$$\frac12-\frac{x^2}{24}\le f(x)\le\frac12$$ so that the intervals are closed, but the conclusion remains the same.

Comment: Hey pls take the interval after limit on $(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4},\frac{1}{2})$ u can check it is $\phi$

Comment: @mSourav: no, $x\ne0$.

Comment: So here my answer is 1/2 am I right

Comment: @mSourav: what else ?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that by [**squeeze theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) from

$$\frac {1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{24}<\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}<\frac {1}{2}$$

since

$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{24}\to \frac12$$

we can conclude that

$$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\to \frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

Limits don't necessarily preserve *strict* inequalities. If you know that $f(x) < g(x)$ and $f(x)\to A$ and $g(x) \to B$, then you can only conclude $A \le B$ (not $A < B$).